Resources for "Game Theoretic" Quant Puzzles
Could I please have some resources that discuss optimal playing strategies in various dice games / card games / casino games and their optimal expected payoffs? I have been encountering many such questions in quant interviews.
For example, I am looking for resources where I can practice questions of the following type:-

You repeatedly roll a 6-sided fair die. You may choose to either accept the face value of the current roll, or pay $1 and roll again. You may do this infinitely many times. Find the optimal strategy and the optimal payoff.

You repeatedly roll a die and track the running sum of the face values. You may choose to stop at any point and walk away with the current running sum, or you may choose to roll again. However, if you roll a number that has already been rolled before, you lose and the game ends. Find the optimal expected payoff and the optimal strategy.



I'm not a game theory expert so it's possible that I am missing some way of casting these as a game theory problem, but as I see it, these are really more of a probability question. Both I'd expect you can solve by using dynamic programming.

"Resources" would be https://www.amazon.com/dp/B091V2Z257
Challenging Brainteasers for Interviews
by Rados Radoicic, Ivan Matic, and Dan Stefanica, https://www.amazon.com/dp/1734531223
Probability and Stochastic Calculus Quant Interview Questions  , https://www.amazon.com/dp/097975769X
150 Most Frequently Asked Questions on Quant Interviews ,  and similar books. IMO, "discussions" would belong in a probability forum if it's purely about maximizing the expected return, but if you add risk aversion / appetite / behavioral finance to the mix, then they might belong in QF.

By the way, I posed the first problem to Google Bard AI (I made the die n-sides for more generality). Bard's response was: "Optimal Strategy: The optimal strategy involves setting a target value, let's call it $T$. You should continue to roll the die until you roll a number greater than or equal to $T$. Once you do, you should accept the roll. Optimal Payoff: To determine the optimal target value $T$, we need to consider the expected value of the game given a particular $T$. Let $E(T)$ denote the expected value when the target is $T$. We can calculate $E(T)$ recursively:

$E(T) = (1/n) * (T + (T+1) + ... + n) + (n-T)/n * (1 + E(T))$. The first term represents the probability of rolling a number greater than or equal to $T$ and accepting it, and the second term represents the probability of rolling a number less than $T$ and paying $1 to roll again. To find the optimal $T$, we can calculate $E(T)$ for different values of $T$ and choose the one that maximizes the expected value. However, there's a more efficient approach:

** Intuitive Approach:**
Intuitively, we want to set $T$ high enough to maximize the potential payoff but low enough to minimize the expected cost of additional rolls. A good starting point is to consider the average value of a roll, which is $(n+1)/2$.
If we set $T$ slightly higher than the average, we can often get a higher payoff without incurring too many additional rolls. However, setting $T$ too high can lead to many additional rolls and a lower overall expected value.
Practical Implementation:
While the exact optimal $T$ might depend on the specific value of $n,$

a practical strategy is to set $T$ to be the ceiling of the average value of a roll. This means:
$T = \mathrm{ceil}((n+1)/2)$
This strategy provides a good balance between maximizing the potential payoff and minimizing the expected cost of additional rolls.
By following this strategy, you can maximize your expected payoff in the long run." This seems like a better answer than a lot of what we get on SE.

@DimitriVulis Thank you for the explanation! Just one doubt, how does one figure out that the optimal strategy is of the form "roll until you cross a target T" ?

@Rylan I would think that the game theory part lies in figuring out the optimal strategy (like in problem 1)? Maybe I'm wrong and there's an easier way of figuring out the optimal strategy. Finding the expected payoff "given" some strategy doesn't bother me at all. However, coming up with that particular optimal strategy is quite challenging for me.

@Quanter IMO, game theory implies there's someone else making decisions that we also have to think about. As for the issue of it being challenging to find the optimal strategy, practice helps! (Of course, your question is asking about more problems you can practice on -- and I broadly agree with the resources Dmitri posted.)

For both of these problems, it can be helpful to think: what's the relevant information I need to make my decision? And what are the easiest cases to solve?
For 1. it should be clear that you won't roll again if you roll a six, and you should convince yourself that you will roll again if you roll a one. For two, I hope it's apparent that if you roll one of everything, you won't roll again. You can work backwards from here. (note that your strategy won't necessarily be easy to describe in words, but you will be able to determine if it makes sens to roll again if youve rolled eg a 1 3 and 5).

@Rylan Understood. Thank you Rylan!
